# Android In-app billing: the item you were attempting to purchase could not be found

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I know there is a lot of questions about this out there but I've already looked at all of them! Especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918190/the-item-you-were-attempting-to-purchase-could-not-be-found-android-in-app-bil) which has a lot of other questions inside it. But I still keep getting the "the item you were attempting to purchase could not be found" message. I have no idea what I might be missing here.

I basically did everything the user of the question I've mentioned above did:

The in-app item has the status "Active".

I have entered an account other than my developer account in "testing access".

I am using a device with the primary account in the "testing access" and not the developer account.

I have double checked the spelling of my SKU.

The exact same .apk was uploaded to Developer Console and installed on the test device.

I have double checked the license key.

I have waited more than 12 hours for SKU and testing accounts to be propagated.

I've also did what he marked as the correct answer, that is publishing the app on the alpha channel (I've already tried the beta channel too) but it just won't go!

Anyone could help me please? I don't have reputation enough to make a comment so I've made another question

Comment: Are you using the latest version of google play app?

Answer (score 0):

I found that you actually have to publish the app before you can do any testing.  That is not what the Google documentation says, and was not true when I implemented the v1 version of the API many years ago.  But I do know I was always getting those purchase item could not be found errors until I really published my version of the TrivialDrive app.